# Correct Case for has_many :through when both Classes are UPPERCASE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two classes, `PSA` and `ZIP` and the are related by `PSAZIP` by has_many: & :through.

I am having errors thrown with the following in each class:

psa.rb (genereated by `rails g scaffold PSA`)

```
class Psa < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :psazips
  has_many :zips, :through => psazips
end
```

psazip.rb (genereated by `rails g scaffold PSAZIP`)

```
class Psazip < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :psa
  belongs_to :zip
end
```

zip.rb (genereated by `rails g scaffold ZIP`)

```
class Zip < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many:psazips
  has_many:psas, :through => :psazips
end
```

What is the syntax and case grammar for when both Classes are entirely Uppercase?  When I have two other class relationships (`PSA` and `State`, the rb file name is `psa_state.rb`).

Do I have to rename the `psazip.rb` to `psa_zip.rb`? if so, where else do I need to make the change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have should work as is.

Rails will convert any class name written in camel case to lowercase/underscore form for file names. It thinks `PSAZIP` is just one word. It doesn't see it as camel case, so it generates `psazip` instead of `psa_zip`. Had you used `PsaZip` or `PSAZip`, it would have generated `psa_zip`.

But, everything should work as you have it, so long as you consistenly use the class name `Psazip`.